# Trying to classify my own images with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I have just downloaded tensorflow and I'm trying to classify some images of my own through the command line.

What I've done until now is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

#and finally, to install and run tensorflow classifier
$python classify_image.py
```

which worked fine. However I cannot find how to supply my own images for classification. I'm aware of the --image_file filename.jpg however I cannot find where the images are supposed to be stored in order for this to work. I've tried giving the absolute path,

```
$python classify_image.py --image_file /home/usr/Desktop/ball.jpg
```

but I get a "file does not exist" warning.

Full error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQHPc.jpg
Interesting thing is that now that I restarted the virtual machine it re-downloaded the model for some reason.

Is there something more to this, do I have to change the source code in some way?

Comment: You seem to have lost a slash - `/home/usr/`

Comment: @AndreySobolev it was there in the shell, missed it here

Answer (score 0):

The scripts, including examples, are all stored in your pip installation path.

Note that you have to pip install before: `sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`.

For instance, as above, it is probably here:
`./usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py`.

Comment: yes, I have installed it. forgot to mention it here. I have also located where classify_image is, but I cannot transfer files there.

Comment: Did it download the inception data successfully?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot in the thread. As you might notice, for some reason it re-downloaded the model.

Comment: Turns out I just had to add them in the imagenet folder. I was confused because I'm new to using linux, and couldn't understand why I couldn't copy in there. Turns out sudo mv was all that was necessary to move them into that folder.